# using the augPredict and predict functions after nlme with fixed effects

Tags: r, nlme

Since I updated R to version 3.2.3 and the package 'nlme' to version 3.1-124 I am unable to use the `augPredict` (and predict) functions for models including mixed effects. Below you can find an example of my code using the Soybean data that are provided with the `nlme` package.
I get the error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Variety' not found`
Am I doing something wrong (although this code worked fine on my data in previous versions), or is this a bug in the software?

```
#base model
M1.lis <- nlsList( SSlogis, data=Soybean)
M1.lis

M1.nlme <- nlme( M1.lis )
M1.nlme
summary(M1.nlme)

M1.Fix<-fixef(M1.nlme)

#add fixed effects
M2.nlme <- update( M1.nlme, fixed = Asym + xmid + scal ~ Variety,
                         start = c(M1.Fix[1], 0, M1.Fix[2], 0, M1.Fix[3], 0))

summary(M2.nlme)
plot( augPred(M2.nlme, level = 0:1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It apparently was a bug which has been fixed in 'nlme' version 3.1-126